# Banned Tag Proposal: Hackintosh

Tags: support, tags

Due to the legal gray area that exists with regards to building or running Hackintosh machines we have always discouraged these question on SU since it would attract unnecessary attention to the site to avoid any issues going forward.

Also every time someone posts a Hackintosh question they either get down voted into oblivion or a 15 comment this is not legal battle ensues, and should be avoided if possible.

Could we please add the [hackintosh](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hackintosh) tag to the list of banned tags for the site.

Comment: +1, I generally downvote Hackintosh based questions.

Comment: +1, I agree. What about existing questions that are not tagged as hackintosh?

Comment: Just change OSX86 to hackintosh (only 4 hits though)

Comment: I think it's pretty sad that people would close and downvote just because something might be used illegally.  That would pretty much eliminate all computer questions.

Comment: @Lance: There's a difference between "might be used illegally" and "might not be legal".

Comment: I think you are all missing the point here - it's really sad that *you can purchase something from Apple*, but *you can't use it however you'd like*.

Comment: @Breakthrough I think you're missing the point. I'd say its more: *you can purchase a license to use Apple's work under their conditions **then break that license** when using it however you'd like.* Bottom line is if you don't agree to the license, don't agree to it when you hand over your money.

Comment: @LanceRoberts Well, this site does talk about some para-legal issues, such as cracking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I already closed these on sight, so you've got my vote

Comment: Awesome, let's not speak about chemistry reactions of arsenic because assassins might used it  to make poisons. Or better let's completely ban chemistry. Is this turning into a religious dogma of "Do not even dare to touch, watch or think"?

Comment: Might I remind you this was posted 6 years ago? ;-)

Comment: Yes, but it seems the problem is still very actual.

Comment: This answer provides no reasoning, facts, or anything other then what I see as personal bias.