# Which pro-forma comments already exist for SuperUser?

Tags: support

I'm using AutoReviewComments script and want to customize it like I did for Ask Ubuntu.
[image: screenshot]
I'm using https://raw.github.com/askubuntu/ProFormaComments/master/comments.jsonp as remote source.

Comment: Nice. We've moved to [GitHub too](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments). You may be interested in [this](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments/issues/6), and [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13278/autoreviewcomment-script-devel).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I decided to adopt that one I'm using in AU. Currently it has such contents:

```
###[Q]Abandonment! 
This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered. If you solved it, please post an answer explaining how it was solved (answering your own questions is not merely permitted, but [encouraged when there is no other answer that does the job](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)). If the question no longer applies you may voluntarily delete/close it.

###[Q]Merge accounts
Please use the contact us link at the bottom of this page to ask for your unregistered account and your new registered account to be merged. Thanks.

###[Q]More than one question asked
It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your questions. Thanks!

###[Q]OP providing facts in a comment
The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

###[A]Answers just to say Thanks!
Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://$SITEURL$/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the $SITENAME$ way of saying thank you.

###[A]Nothing but a URL (and isn't spam)
Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

###[A]Requests to OP for further information
This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://$SITEURL$/privileges/comment). For the moment I've added the comment for you, and I'm flagging this post for deletion.

###[A]OP using an answer for further information
Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.

###[A]New question as an answer
If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://$SITEURL$/questions/ask) button.

###[A]Another user adding a 'Me too!'
If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://$SITEURL$/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](http://$SITEURL$/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

###[A]Comments as an answer (new users)
Please don't add comments as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://$SITEURL$/privileges) to upvote answers you like, or to add actual comments when seeking clarification of any issues. If you have a new question please [ask it](http://$SITEURL$/questions/ask).

###[A]Comments as an answer (experienced users)
Please don't add comments as answers. Use actual comments when seeking clarification of any issues.

###[A]OP adding a new question as an answer
Remember this is a Q&A site - so keep on editing your question with new information - this section is for actual answers. If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://$SITEURL$/questions/ask) button.

###[A]Answer that is a question
If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://$SITEURL$/questions/ask) button.

###[A]Duplicate answers.
Please do not post duplicate answers on different questions. It just creates more work for the moderators. If the questions are so similar that the same answer works on each, then the later of the two is likely a duplicate and should be flagged as such.

###OP should accept an answer
@[OP]: If [type here] answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://$SITEURL$/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.
```

This post is CW, so anyone is welcome to maintain and extend it.

Answer (score 2):

This is my set:

```
### Q: Off-topic (be sure to fill in information)
Voting to close as *off-topic*, because questions about [topic] do not belong on $SITENAME$. See the [help center](http://$SITEURL$/help/on-topic) for details. This question should be migrated to [site] soon; please do not cross-post, as this will happen automatically once enough close votes have been cast on this question. To ensure you retain control of the question, please create an account at [site] and associate it with your $SITENAME$ account.

### Q: Off-topic enterprise hardware or software
Unfortunately, enterprise hardware or software questions are off-topic here—please try [sf] instead. See the [help/on-topic] for details. (Please don't cross-post—if you post your question there, you should delete the question here.)

### Q: Hardware recommendation
Unfortunately, hardware recommendation questions are off-topic as they [tend to become obsolete quickly](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) and often aren't useful to other readers. Instead of asking for a specific product, you might want to consider asking about *how* to find a particular device that meets your needs.

### Q: Product, service, or learning material recommendation
Unfortunately, questions which ask for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly and attract subjective answers. For advice on how to ask a question which may require recommending software, see [this Meta $SITENAME$ post](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5372/).

### Q: Hackintosh
Questions about running OS X on non-Apple hardware ("Hackintosh") are off-topic because of the questionable legality of doing so. See [Are "Hackintosh" questions allowed?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471)

### Q: Too broad
Unfortunately, your question as written is too broad to be easily answerable. We can answer your question better if you edit it to add more details so that the range of possible answers isn't as broad. For more information on how to ask a good question, see the [help center](http://$SITEURL$/help/how-to-ask).

### Q: Question only asking for code
Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://$SITEURL$/help/closed-questions).

### Q: Unclear what you're asking
Unfortunately, your question as written is unclear and difficult for us to understand. We can answer your question better if you edit it to improve spelling, grammar, and formatting or to add additional information about the specific issue at hand. For more information on how to ask a good question, see the [help center](http://$SITEURL$/help/how-to-ask).

### Q: Primarily opinion-based
Unfortunately, your question as written is primarily opinion-based and will likely be closed because overly subjective questions are not a good fit for our Q&A model. The help center has more guidance on [how to ask a good question](http://$SITEURL$/help/how-to-ask) and [what kinds of questions to avoid asking](http://$SITEURL$/help/dont-ask).

### Q: Too many separate questions
Your post contains too many separate questions. This is not a good fit for our Q&A format, so please create separate posts for each distinct issue you have. See also: [One post with multiple questions or multiple posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223)

### A: User treating site as forum (generic)
Unfortunately, this doesn't answer the question. We're a Q&A community, not a conventional forum, so answer posts must answer (or attempt to answer) the question—answer posts which fail to do so are subject to deletion.

### A: Question posted as answer
Unfortunately, this doesn't answer the question. We're a Q&A community, not a conventional forum, so answer posts must answer (or attempt to answer) the question—answer posts which fail to do so are subject to deletion. If you'd like to ask a *new* question, click on the **[Ask Question](http://$SITEURL$/questions/ask)** button at the top of the page and enter your question. You may want to include a link to the original question for context.

### A: Comment posted as answer
Unfortunately, this doesn't answer the question. We're a Q&A community, not a conventional forum, so answer posts must answer (or attempt to answer) the question—answer posts which fail to do so are subject to deletion.  If you need clarification or have a question or concern about another post, please leave a comment on that post—you can always comment on your own posts, and you can [comment on other people's posts](http://$SITEURL$/help/privileges/comment) once you earn 50 [reputation](http://$SITEURL$/help/whats-reputation).

### A: "Thanks!" posted as answer
Unfortunately, this doesn't answer the question. We're a Q&A community, not a conventional forum, so answer posts must answer (or attempt to answer) the question—answer posts which fail to do so are subject to deletion. Instead of saying "thanks!", you can [upvote posts](http://$SITEURL$/help/privileges/vote-up) you find useful once you earn 15 [reputation](http://$SITEURL$/help/whats-reputation).

### A: "Me too!" answer
Unfortunately, this doesn't answer the question. We're a Q&A community, not a conventional forum, so answer posts must answer (or attempt to answer) the question—answer posts which fail to do so are subject to deletion. If you are interested in new answers to this question, you can [mark it as a favorite](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585) so you can track it on your user profile. With enough reputation, you can also [place a bounty on the question](http://$SITEURL$/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw attention to it.

### A: Link-only answer
Although this may answer the question, you should give a more detailed description of the linked content and explain how it relates to the question. This will help ensure that this answer remains useful in the event the linked page is removed or goes offline. For more information, see [this Meta Stack Exchange post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259).

### A: Answer recommending software
Please exercise caution when recommending software. As written, your answer may be seen as spam. Your answer should include a description of the software and how it addresses the question. More information: [How do I recommend software in my answers?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5329)

### A: Unexplained code
Can you explain what this code does and how it addresses the problem given by the OP? Unexplained code can appear untrusted and dangerous to users.

### A: Duplicate answer
Unfortunately, your answer only duplicates content from another answer. Each answer is expected to contribute something new to the question, so answer posts that only duplicate existing content are not considered useful and are subject to deletion.

### C: Downvotes on spam/offensive posts
**[Please don't downvote spam or offensive posts.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193916/why-shouldnt-i-downvote-spam-that-ive-already-flagged)** Doing so makes them harder to find, allowing the spam or offensive content to remain on the site longer. The Community account automatically downvotes posts that are flagged as spam or offensive.
```

Answer (score 2):

These are mine (for answers only)

```
###Thanks
Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://$SITEURL$/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the $SITENAME$ way of saying thank you.

###Link
Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

###Not an answer
This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://$SITEURL$/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://$SITEURL$/help/privileges/comment).

###OP answer
Please use the **Post Your Answer** button only for actual answers. You should edit your original post to add additional information.

###New question as answer
This is **not** an answer to the original question. If you have a new question please [ask your own question](http://$SITEURL$/questions/ask) (referencing this one for context if it helps).

###Me too
If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://$SITEURL$/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](http://$SITEURL$/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

###No answer
Please read [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://$SITEURL$/help/no-one-answers)

###Explain
While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

###Code only
Could you please [edit] your answer to give an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.

###Answer in question
Please don't [edit] your question to include the answer, answer your own question. Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://$SITEURL$/help/self-answer)

###Please read again
Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

###Duplicate answer
This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.
```