# What flag to use for questions related to 'Hackintosh(s)'

Tags: feature-request, flagging

This question was recently asked:

https://superuser.com/q/1016904/465600

This is a question really to do with the Hackintosh community but I am not sure what to flag it as.

Hackintosh doesn't belong really on another topic in this site and it is about computer hardware and software.

So what should I flag this as?

Comment: Out of scope, variety of reasons, Violation of EULA would be one of them

Comment: ""Should be closed..." --> Off topic --> not within the scope defined in the help center, as Ramhound suggested.  In general, if you aren't sure which reason to pick, you can use "in need of moderator intervention" and write in your reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason Hackintosh questions are banned is because [there was a meta discussion which concluded they should be banned](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed). So write a comment citing this meta question, and flag as “blatantly off-topic” (which is a very bad name indeed, since the question isn't off-topic but instead banned by policy, but it's the only possibility).

(Why are Hackintosh questions banned despite the pro answer scoring higher than the against answer? Because in the distant past the pro answer scored lower, and the policy never changed.)

Comment: Thanks for that help... Question was sorted out anyway but surely there should be a new flag that deals with questions like these...

Comment: They are very very rare I have seen maybe 20 in the last 3 years total not saying there were not more then 20 but I do see a lot of questions

Comment: How I can get the policy changed? Someone flagged my question and pointed me here. I NEED the question answered, because it is literally needed for me to able to afford food and medicine (and Hackintosh is not illegal in my country).

What is the process to make the now most upvoted answer over there the new policy?

Comment: @speeder Argue that the difference in voting justifies changing the policy. It's reasonable to not change the policy every time one of the answers has one more vote than the other. On the other hand, the pro answer has been in the lead for a long time. Is a 34/21 ratio enough to justify a change? I don't know. By the way, Hackintosh questions are allowed on [unix.se] — but we have no history of Hackintosh questions, so I don't know if we have the expertise to answer.

Comment: I thought of asking there, but it is a question about many OSes, Windows included, and the community here is larger, thus why I asked here.