# What is the best way to answer a question that violates software license terms?

Tags: support

I just came across a question titled "[UEFI Interactive Shell comes up when trying to run OSX in Virtualbox](https://superuser.com/questions/1140335/uefi-interactive-shell-comes-up-when-trying-to-run-osx-in-virtualbox)." As you can see, I responded to it with, "I am guessing the host operating system is not OSX?" to which he replied "That's correct in this case." While it is possible to use OSX in VirtualBox, doing so violates Apple's license terms for the operating system.

I am sure that this has come up before on here, but how do we handle situations such as this? Would it be more appropriate for me to respond with an actual explanation, or should I just simply state that doing this violates Apple's license terms? For now, I decided to respond with the latter, but would the former be more appropriate for the scope of the site?

I apologize in advance if this is a silly question that should have an obvious answer, but I am not familiar enough with the law to know if Stack Exchange is at any legal risk by allowing information about how to do something like that to be propagated on its network.

Comment: In *theory* he could legally run OS X on virtualbox on OS X on a mac

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Yes, but he explicitly stated that the host OS was not OSX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We close them as off-topic: Reason "Other".

I use the following canned response:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the use of OSX on non-Apple hardware is a legal grey area and as a result "Hackintosh" questions have been deemed [off-topic](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed)