# Hackintosh vs. fair use

Tags: discussion, scope, legality

Note: Cross-posted on [SE Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/93140/11627) to get thoughts from legal experts there.

---

Follow up question to [*Revisit the Hackintosh policy*](https://meta.superuser.com/q/12050/516482).

Use case:

- I create a [userscript](https://superuser.com/edit-tag-wiki/9157) (in a [licenced] Windows or a Linux) and release it under GNU GPLv3 http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html.
- I'd like to test the script with browsers available in macOS as well.
- To be able to achieve this with the x86-based systems mentioned above (I do not own or have access to any Mac) I get a macOS ISO image and install macOS in a local VM.

Does this comply with fair use's "[*public interest in the wider distribution and use of creative works*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use)?

If the answer is (more) "yes" are questions regarding such a use case tolerated here on SU?

Comment: So long as it would work on a standard Mac it's fine. We shouldn't have to care about your using a hackintosh for the browser to work. Setting up and using the hackintosh is your problem and that's where we draw the line.

Comment: @Mokubai Thanks for the reply. However, "We _shouldn't_ have to care" is a bit _backdoor-like_. :) Is this "official" SU community/mod policy or your personal opinion?

Comment: If you can focus 100% inside the browser and know that the system has absolutely no issues related to it being "hackintosh" and what you are doing is exactly equivalent to a "real" Mac then we do not and should not care. If you cannot make that guarantee and think whatever issue you could be having is due to the nature of your hackintosh operating system then it is possible that your question is simply off topic. We do not deal with the hackintosh side, and you may need to find someone with a real Mac to prove the issue is the same on proper hardware.

Comment: Website and webapp problems would also be broadly off topic on [su] except insofar as the problem is with the browser itself. Userscripts may be on topic at [webapps.se].

Comment: @Mokubai The real use case is neither a website, nor webapp, nor userscript issue (I know the proper SE sites for these) but the macOS installation process inside a VM (it stucks at selecting the start drive). That's a topic for SU in principle, I guess, but it's definitely not "_100% inside the browser_" hence apparently off-topic here. Right?

Comment: Yes. If your problem is entirely about the setup and use of that hackintosh machine then we simply do not support it at all and your question will be closed as a result. Whether it is "legal" or "fair use" is an argument for elsewhere, we simply do not support that at all.

Comment: @GeroldBroser--OnStrike - If your hackintosh VM has a problem we can’t help, the problem very likely, has to do with attempting to run MacOS on unsupported hardware.